# If GET isn't ... or if GET is empty

Tags: php, string, get, isset

I want to add `class sidebg` when the user doesn't visit the page 'wijzigpagina' or if the `$_GET page` is empty.

I tried adding `&& empty($_GET["page"])`:

```
<div id="wrapper"<?php if(isset($_GET["page"]) && $_GET["page"] !== "wijzigpagina" && empty($_GET["page"])) { echo ' class="sidebg"'; } ?>>
```

But that didn't work.

Comment: `isset($_GET["page"])` and `empty($_GET["page"])`???

Comment: empty($_GET["page"] and  isset($_GET["page"] together dont make any sense

Comment: @VladKrasovsky Sure they do. `""` is set, but is empty.

Comment: `&&` stands for `AND`, `||` for `OR`. now read again what you wrote: _...the page 'wijzigpagina' **or** if the $_GET page is empty_

Comment: I think little different, `isset` and not `empty` and not `wijzigpagina`..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just code exactly what you said:

```
if (empty($_GET['page']) || $_GET['page'] != "wijzigpagina")
```

If `$_GET['page']` is set and has a non-false value, the second part of the `OR` expression will be evaluated and check if the value is not equal to `"wijzigpagina"`. So any values of `$_GET['page']` other than "wijzigpagina" will add your class.

Comment: Perfect, and what if I want to add an array to 'wijzigpagina' so I can add multiple pages?

Comment: Instead of checking that it's not equal to one value in the second part of the OR, you could use `!in_array($_GET['page'], $multiple_pages)`

Comment: Sorry, I can't really follow you, where is $multiple_pages defined?

Comment: `$multiple_pages` was my attempt at a generic name for the array of pages you referred to. I was assuming you would have that defined before this check.

Answer (score 0):

You should be careful of using the `empty` and `isset` at the same time.

You have the answer on your question, **I want to add class sidebg when the user doesn't visit the page 'wijzigpagina' or if the $_GET page is empty.**

So did this,

```
if(empty($_GET["page"]) || $_GET["page"] !== "wijzigpagina")
```

The first condition is for *the user doesn't visit the page 'wijzigpagina'* and then *or as ||* and then the second condition *if the $_GET page is empty*.

So its simple.